# Can't call my function from inside onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, discord

I've got this onEdit function that first checks if the edit made is inside a defined area. It then gets the row that was edited, logs it, and is supposed to send the same log message to a Discord channel via a webhook. I can't seem to get it to work correctly. the postMessageToDiscord function works fine when I call it from inside a different function I have, but not from inside the onEdit one. Any ideas as to why it working?

onEdit Func:

```
function onEdit(edit){
 if (
    edit.range.columnStart >= 3 &&
    edit.range.columnEnd <= 9 &&
    edit.range.rowStart >= 13 &&
    edit.range.rowEnd <= 101
  )
  {
    Logger.log("Edit in range");
    var editRow = (edit.range.rowStart, edit.range.rowEnd)
  }
  Logger.log("Row " + String(editRow) + " has been edited on Cadet Log " + edit.range.getSheet().getSheetName());
  postMessageToDiscord("Row " + String(editRow) + " has been edited on Cadet Log " + edit.range.getSheet().getSheetName());
}
```

postMessageToDiscord func:

```
function postMessageToDiscord(message) {

  message = message || "Hunter fucked up, disregard."

  var discordUrl = LINK REDACTED FOR SECURITY;
  var payload = JSON.stringify({content: message});

  var params = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```

Comment: For simple triggers, such as `onEdit(e)`, you cannot make calls to services that require user authorization (`UrlFetchApp.fetch()` in your case); [see restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions). You have to create an installable trigger and have users authorize your script before use. [See documentation on installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Answer (score 0):

Provided by [@Dimu Designs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58790239/cant-call-my-function-from-inside-onedit#comment103862348_58790239)

For simple triggers, such as `onEdit(e)`, you cannot make calls to services that require user authorization (`UrlFetchApp.fetch()` in your case); see [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions). You have to create an installable trigger and have users authorize your script before use. See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) on installable triggers.